# Can't get jQuery .change() event to fire in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, turbolinks

So I've been reading about how to get jQuery and Turbolinks to play nicely together for hours now and I still can't get .change() to fire. I've added the jquery-turbolinks gem to no avail. Here is my CoffeeScript:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#data_type").change ->
    dt = $("#data_type").val()
    switch dt
      when "radio" then $("#radio_conditional").show()
      when "checklist" then $("#checklist_conditional").show()
      when "integer", "decimal"
        $("#units_conditional").show()
        $("#length_conditional").show()
      else $("#radio_conditional", "#checklist_conditional", "#units_conditional", "#length_conditional").hide()
  return
return
```

Basically I want certain fields on my form to only show when a certain data type is selected for the selector #data_type. I think $(document).ready is working, but nothing happens when I change the data type, no matter which type I choose. I know jQuery is working because I can enter $("#radio_conditional").hide() in the console and it works. I have a feeling I'm missing something simple here but I can't figure out. Any ideas?

Here is my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require nested_form_fields
//= require turbolinks
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
//= stub pages
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.2.3"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Turbolinks also screws up jquery. This gem fixes it.
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use figaro for setting environment variables
gem 'figaro'

# Use simple_form for forms
gem 'simple_form'

# Use nested_form_fields to create forms for nested associations
gem 'nested_form_fields'

# Use bootstrap for easy CSS
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your js in this:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

    // your code

$(document).on('page:change', ready);
```

That always did it for me.

Comment: Seems like it should work, but I tried it with and without jquery-turbolinks, and still nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. Turns out I was trying to select "#data_type" at page ready, but it didn't actually exist on the page until I clicked "Add Variable", and thus the selector never selected. I changed the script to fire on clicking "Add Variable." All fixed now, thanks!